# Routing Url confined only in a specific folder using ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

Suppose I have a ASP.NET Web Forms Application project. The tree structure of Solution Explorer looks like this:

```
WebApplication1
|
|__ App_Start
|   |__ RouteConfig.cs
|
|__ View
|   |__ Default.aspx
|   |__ Login.aspx
|   |__ Product
|   |   |__ ProductDetails.aspx
|   |   |__ ...
|   |__ ...
|
|__ Global.asax
|__ ...
```

Notice that I have a folder called `View` which contains *aspx* files.

**I want to achieve:**

- `View` text will not shown in address bar. For example: `www.mysite.com/default` but not `www.mysite.com/view/default`.
- Accessing any pages (*aspx* files) outside `View` folder (if any) will be routed to another page (such as *Forbidden.aspx*).

**What I have done so far:**

- `Global.asax`:

  ```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  }
  ```
- `RouteConfig.cs`:

  ```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
      var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();    // Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls
      settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
      routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

      routes.MapPageRoute("Default", string.Empty, "~/View/Default.aspx");
  }
  ```

Now what to do next to achieve the above two goals using ASP.NET Web Forms (not ASP.NET MVC)?